# Trouble Moving Opencart to new hosting error message

Tags: database, opencart

I have been having trouble getting my Opencart site to work when moving it to new hosting.

Firstly I downloaded all my files via ftp onto my computer then uploaded them onto my new hosting.

I exported the database from the old hosting and imported it into my new hosting.

I have then changed the config file in the root and also the admin to the new database info but I am not getting this error message:

Fatal error: Class 'Modeldesignbanner' not found in /homepages/34/d285756979/htdocs/portfolio/websites/ecommerce/agc-tools/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_loader.php on line 36

Ps. I can access the admin section of the site but just get that error on the front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the file

```
/catalog/model/design/banner.php
```

is missing. re-upload it and that error should go

Comment: You have saved the day!! I have spent hours looking in the vqmod folders. The file was actually there but completely empty of code? It must have happened during ftp download. Thankyou so much!!!

Comment: Yeah sometimes when transferring via certain FTP clients it doesn't transfer correctly and you end up with a blank file, but the client still thinks its uploaded